# How to open full path of a file in ido-find-file?

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

I am looking to open a full path as fast as possible.Using `ido-find-file` makes it difficult. When I apply `ido-find-file`, following line show up.

```
Find file: ~/folder/work
```

Here I have a full path(ex: `/home/user/folder_1/work/file.py`) and I want to open it.

In `helm-find-files` I can do `C-a` , `C-k` and paste the full path and enter to open it. But in `ido-find-file`, `C-a` does not jump to beginning of the line. Also when I remove everything `/` at the beginning remains, so pasting full path causes: `//home/user/folder_1/work/file.py`

When I play around, I found out `C-e` opens `[EDIT]` section and I can do `C-a`, `C-k` and paste full line. Than enter does not open the file right away, it jumps to ido selection menu and I have to press enter again. Maybe can it open the file right away on the `EDIT` section.

---

[image]

`RET`

[image]

`RET`

Comment: Try additional `C-f` (open file with C-x C-f C-f), then `C-a` and `C-k` will work as usual.

Comment: @Y.E. Thanks, it is excatly what I was looking for! Is it possible to make `C-x C-f` to run `C-x C-f C-f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm turning my own comment and answer to the follow-up question into this post.

`ido-mode`, among other things, remaps `Emacs` default key binding `C-x C-f` (`M-x find-file`) to its own function for files opening `M-x ido-find-file`.

With all the conveniences provided by `ido-find-file`, there're still cases when this function "gets in the way". One of such cases you had described.

To overcome such obstacles, `ido-mode` allows to fallback to the `Emacs` default (non-Ido) `find-file`, by hitting additional `C-f`. Hence, the full key binding for opening a file with `find-file` when `ido-mode` is enabled would be `C-x C-f C-f`.

Note, that you could achieve the same result by calling `M-x find-file` directly (without a key binding).

To learn more about the bindings for falling back (and other, as they call it, "magic" actions) in `ido-mode` see `C-h f ido-magic-(forward|backward|delete)-char`.

Answering your comment

> Is it possible to make C-x C-f to run C-x C-f C-f?

supposedly it's more clear now this, kind of, wouldn't make sense with enabled `ido-mode`. I'd suggest using one of the methods described above or disabling `ido-mode` when you don't need it.

Comment: I am not sure why but on my end `M-x find-file` does not open the same fallback when I do `C-x C-f C-f` :-( // Please see my ido-setup: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/46dfabd82c0fa250293b5c1f8d0b18fb

Comment: Hm, I don't know. Might be take a look at `ido-everywhere` and `C-h f find-file`. And then, if that shows nothing interesting, start with `emacs -Q` and add settings one by one. Let know if you find the cause ;-)

Comment: Ah, and note there might be discrepancies in our experiences according to the Emacs version used. (I'm on the (almost) latest source.). In my setup I currently only configure for ido `(setq ido-default-file-method 'selected-window      ido-default-buffer-method 'selected-window)`. So starting debugging with the `ido` default configs might give some results too.

Comment: We need to add `(require 'ido)` before `(setq ido...`, right?

Comment: Yes, sure, that would be a preferred way (I omitted it from the snippet I sent before). Though `ido` is a built-in package in the most recent Emacs versions, so, technically, it should be loaded even without explicitly requiring it (in those versions). We'd also need `(ido-mode 1)` to switch the mode on.